# How to skip header and footer for certain routes in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following code which renders an app with a header and footer for all pages.

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Home from './homeComponent';
import Login from './loginComponent';
import Dashboard from './dashboardComponent';

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              ... more routes
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**layout.js**

```
import Header from './headerComponent'
import Footer from './footerComponent'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What is the best way to skip rendering of the header and footer for certain pages like Home and Login routes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd recommend creating two layouts with their own header and footers and a private route:

**Public Layout**

```
export const PublicLayout = (props) => <div>
<PublicHeader/>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
    <Route exact path='/signin' component={SigninForm} />
    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />         
  </Switch>
<PublicFooter/>
```

**Protected Layout**

```
export const ProtectedLayout = (props) => <div>
<ProtectedHeader/>
 <Switch>
   <PrivateRoute exact path='/app/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
   <Route component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
<ProtectedFooter/>
```

**Define high-level routes in app.js:**

```
export default () => {
  return <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/app' component={ProtectedLayout} />
      <Route path='/' component={PublicLayout} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
}
```

**Define PrivateRoute:**

```
export default ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    window.globalState.isAuthenticated() ? (
      <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: '/signin',
        state: {from: props.location}
      }} />
    )
  )} />
)
```

Comment: This seems to be a cleaner solution. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Can you please help me in giving class component solution for the same??

Comment: Hi can some one explain why in high-level routes in app.js the order of routes matter. I tried same but ended up reversing the order and the application did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah i know a bit late .

Visual studio 2019

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import NavMenu from '../components/NavMenu';

export default props => (
    <div>
        {window.location.pathname !== '/login' ? <NavMenu /> : null}        
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
    </div>
);
```

i hope somebody helps out there.. !!! Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

I made some solution while solving the problem.

First You can wrap the `Switch` in a website header and footer

```js
<BrowserRouter>

    <WebsiteHeader />

    <Switch>
        <Route/>
        <Route/>
        <Route/>
    </Switch>

    <WebsiteFooter/>

<BrowserRouter>
```

then inside the header or footer wrap the components using `withRouter` from `'react-router-dom'` so you can access the routes props

```js
const WebsiteHeader = props => {
    if (props.location.pathname == "/register") return null;
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <DesktopHeader {...props} />
            <MobileHeader {...props} />
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default withRouter(WebsiteHeader);
```

Comment: I think the `WebsiteHeader` can't received `props.location` because it's out of the switch!

Answer (score 1):

Use `render`

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard" render={props => <Layout><Dashboard {...props} /></Layout>} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
  </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

For forcefully refresh Header inside routing.
use forceRefresh={true}

```
const Routing = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/list/:id" component={ListingApi}/>
                <Route path="/details/:id" component={HotelDetails}/>
                <Route path="/booking/:hotel_name" component={PlaceBooking}/>
                <Route path="/viewBooking" component={ViewBooking}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                <Route  path="/signup" component={RegisterComponent}/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a few different layouts one with header and footer and one without. And then instead of wrapping everything into one layout. I'd just do this wrapping inside each page component. So your components would be like:

**Dashboard component**

```
<SimpleLayout>
  <Dashboard>
</SimpleLayout>
```

**Home component**

```
<MainLayout>
  <Home>
</MainLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<Route path="/" render={(props) => (props.location.pathname !== "/login") && 
    <Header />}>
</Route>

<Route path="/" render={(props) => (props.location.pathname !== "/login") && 
  <Menu />}> 
</Route>

<PrivateRoute path="/scope" component={Scope}  ></PrivateRoute>

<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
```

In this example I'm checking the URL, If the URL is "/Login" I'm removing **Menu** and **header** component

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For forcefully refresh Header inside routing.

```
const Routing = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/list/:id" component={ListingApi}/>
                <Route path="/details/:id" component={HotelDetails}/>
                <Route path="/booking/:hotel_name" component={PlaceBooking}/>
                <Route path="/viewBooking" component={ViewBooking}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginComponent}/>
                <Route  path="/signup" component={RegisterComponent}/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```